# The max of n values, excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range, max

I want to obtain on excel the max value of *n* values from a list of values, the *n* is variable. Here is one example with *n*=5:
[Explanation: it starts at A6 when it have 5 values and enough data to compute the max of the 5 previous values, so it looks backwards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfAcv.png)

Explanation: it starts at A6 when it have 5 values and enough data to compute the max of the 5 previous values, so it looks backwards.

Another example with *n*=10:

[The range is always looking backwards the number of values that the constant is, so if constant =10 then it looks the 10 previous values.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKfkr.png)
What I need is the formula or array formula of the column B that changes the range to look for the max if the constant value changes.

Any questions, ask me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore the below. Here's another solution provided by @tigeravatar that I am leaving up because it's even cleaner than his current solution:

```
=IF(ROW()<=$C$2,"",MAX(OFFSET(A2,0,0,-$C$2,1)))
```

<strike>Another option, though more convoluted. Place in B2 and copy down:</strike>

```
=IF(ROW()=$C$2+1,MAX(OFFSET($A$2,0,0,$C$2,1)),IF(ROW()>$C$2+1,MAX(OFFSET(A2,0,0,$C$2,1)),""))
```

Comment: Using the provided first example where the Constant = 5, cell B7 will return an incorrect result of 10 because B7 will evaluate the range to be A7:A11 instead of the correct range of A3:A7

Comment: You can correct this by having `-$C$2` in the second offset function

Comment: In fact, you could simplify the formula greatly to just be `=IF(ROW()<=$C$2,"",MAX(OFFSET(A2,0,0,-$C$2,1)))`

Comment: thanks @tigeravatar - i thought i checked this, but alas, its having issues. I will just delete it since your answer is dynamite and at this point, you've made my answer dynamite :)

Answer (score 2):

Using your two provided examples, in cell B2 and copied down:

```
=IF(OR($C$2="",ROW(B1)<$C$2),"",MAX(INDEX(A:A,ROW(A2)-$C$2+1):A2))
```

Comment: Is your actual setup different from the examples you've provided?  What error does it give you?  Can you show a more representative example of your actual data?  I did test this and can confirm that it works properly

Comment: ditto on the test!